# Page not found. Spring MVC + Jetty

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to start up Jetty with Spring MVC that contains jsp and @Controller. After start jetty I've got every time WARN if I try to call any pages. For example

> ttp://localhost:8080/getMessageStats/
>
> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-57ad85ed' No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-57ad85ed'

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cloud/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="net.cloud.web.statistics"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

WebServer.class

```
public class WebServer {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebServer.class);

private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/";
private Server httpServer;

@Value("${http_statistics_port}")
private Integer port;

@Value("${start_page_path}")
private String startPagePath;

public void init() {
    try {
        httpServer = new Server(port);
        httpServer.setHandler(getServletContextHandler());
        httpServer.setStopAtShutdown(true);

        httpServer.start();
        log.info("WebServer start ...");
        httpServer.join();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception in http server. Exception: {}", ex.getMessage());
    }

}

private static ServletContextHandler getServletContextHandler() throws IOException {
    WebAppContext contextHandler = new WebAppContext();
    contextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
    contextHandler.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);

    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();

    contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(context)), CONTEXT_PATH);
    contextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    contextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
    contextHandler.setDescriptor("/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    return contextHandler;
}

private static WebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("webapp/WEB-INF/");
    log.info("CONTEXT name {} locations {}", context.getDisplayName(), context.getConfigLocations());

    return context;
}
```

}

GetMessagesStatsController.class

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/getMessageStats")
public class GetMessageStatsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        GetMessageStatsRPC rpc = new GetMessageStatsRPC();

        model.addAttribute("result", rpc.getResult());

        return "getMessageStats";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String generateJsonResponse() {

        GetMessageStatsRPC rpc = new GetMessageStatsRPC();

        return rpc.getResult().toString();
    }
}
```

Project tree (Sorry, no rating to upload picture). Classes:

src/java/main/net/.../WebServer.class;src/java/main/net/.../GetMessagesStatsController.class
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml; src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml; src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/*.jsp;  src/main/webapp/resources/css and src/main/webapp/resources/js

Guys, any idea?

Comment: try accessing like this http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/pageName.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First when the application is deployed it checks the web.xml and gets

`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Then it initializes the DispatcherServlet and initializes the initialization paramerters using

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**(WEB-INF must start with /)**

then in `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` the view resolver resolves the rendering pages.

Change `<property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/pages/"/>`
 to

`<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>`

Finally in your controller `@RequestMapping("/getMessageStats")`

so finally launching the application as

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/getMessageStats/
```

invokes printWelcome() of GetMessagesStatsController and

```
 http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/getMessageStats/json
```

invokes generateJsonResponse()

Comment: where do we set in xml or somewhere else that we need to write <project name> in url?

Comment: So that worked! But now it can't find css files that resolved in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, like <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>. It's gave me No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/css/bootstrap.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-46bcb6d2'

Comment: [Refer this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/) and tell me if you are able to solve it or not

Comment: Seems that I miss something. Could you tell me if I've got project tree: cloud -> src -> main - > java -> net -> ... java classes and cloud -> src -> main - > webapp -> css; cloud -> src -> main - > webapp -> js; cloud -> src -> main - > webapp -> WEB-INFO (web.xml &  etc) Is it right mvc:resources mapping that I wrote in high post by this locations? One more thing I found in my jsp: <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> . What is this ${pageContext.request.contextPath} ?

Comment: what is your exact problem now?

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-57ad85ed'
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-57ad85ed'

Comment: add this line in <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/> in mnc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and put the folder js and css under web-content/resources where make sure resources is a folder under web-content

Comment: I made like u wrote, same WARN. Here is tree webapp -> resources -> css; webapp -> resources -> js;
In JSP : <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: add at the top of jsp page `<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` try like this 
`<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/yourCssPage.css" />" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Made. Same problem: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css]

Comment: add this line `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` to DispatcherServlet.xml and under web-content create a folder resources and put your css folder and js folder in it then call the css like i show you above those two line

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the viewResolver has problem. change the prefix to **/WEB-INF/pages/**, as follow:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Without the slash it means a relative path, so it will find the page at relativePath(getMessageStats/) + prefix(WEB-INF/pages/) + request(getMessageStats) +suffix(.jsp).

Comment: I've changed and it same thing: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/getMessageStats.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' . Real path is webapp/WEB-INF/pages/*.jsp. And if I set <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/"/> it's give same WARN

Comment: @rado Post your build control file. It looks like the war isn't getting assembled properly (there shouldn't be any `webapp` at runtime).

Comment: I run it by MAVEN, in my project like another service, so I don't create WAR file. Interesting thing. If I set <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>. I've got WARN on starting Jetty: 2014-07-03 12:31:46 INFO  [main] Server:300 - jetty-9.1.2.v20140210
2014-07-03 12:31:46 WARN  [main] WebAppContext:501 - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@21069cba{/,file:/home/rado/Development/hg.unisender.com/unicore/cloud/target/classes/webapp/,STARTING}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Any Idea why?

Comment: I thought you can can't access web.xml through path  "/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" could you show us the target/classes directory? you can try to print the whole path of "/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" to check the path

Comment: it's src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml